# from where does log4j picks in which drive to save logs

Tags: java, intellij-idea, log4j, environment-variables

log4jxml looks like below:

```
 <appender name="B2BAPP" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
     <param name="File" value="/LOGS/SAM/B2B_VJ.log"/>   
     <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10000KB"/>
     <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10"/>
     <param name="Append" value="false"/>
     <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %5p [%c:%L] %m%n"/>
     </layout>      
</appender>
```

I dont want to hardcode the path  `<param name="File" value="/LOGS/SAM/B2B_VJ.log"/>` and save my logs to `/LOGS/` but want to use environment variable instead.

I tried making a Environment variable in my intellij runner with name:`LOG_PATH = C:\Logpath` and then passed env variable in log4j.xml but it is not still working:

```
  <param name="file" value="${sys:LOG_PATH}/SAM/B2B_VJ.log"/> I have even tried `env`: instead of `sys` but all in vain.
```

Please help me out, i would be happy if someone can explain me how the logs are getting saved in **c** drive by default from earlier because i have not mentioned anywhere **c** drive .

Answer (score 0):

i try to give some idea for solving your problem...

in my case i use `${sys:catalina.home}/logs` and I set a environment variable  `catalina_home` like this image

[image]

so my log file gose to `G:\server\apache-tomcat-9.0.13\logs` folder...

**my suggestion is create a environment variable name `LOG_PATH` and change your log path in XML file as `${sys:log.path}/SAM/B2B_VJ.log`**

Comment: log.path ?? or LOG_PATH in xml

Comment: try with `log.path`

Comment: try  `${env:log.path}/SAM/B2B_VJ.log`

Comment: @WELoveCode Are you sure that you are setting the environment variable right? Can you print its value out in your code somewhere?

Comment: Also try without the `C:` part. maybe that confuses things. Windows drive letters and backslashes and all that. `/Logpath` should have the same effect as `C:\\Logpath`

Comment: when i try to print my env path on cmd ii am getting a special character appended at front , see image https://i.postimg.cc/zB1wvSMy/111.png

Comment: @Thilo , why i am getting a special characted at begenning https://i.postimg.cc/zB1wvSMy/111.png

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically give file using below code

```
 static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SimpandFile.class);   
 SimpleLayout layout = new SimpleLayout();    
 FileAppender appender = new FileAppender(layout,"filename",false);    
 logger.addAppender(appender);
```